# dismiss of dialog not working

Tags: android, dialog

I have a simple waitdialog which I try to display. Display is working, but dismiss is not working. Dialog shows forever. Does anyone see the problem ?

regards

```
ProgressDialog waitDialog;
waitDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
waitDialog.show(this, "wait","wait");
5secondstask();
waitDialog.dismiss();
```

Also without executing the 5secondstaks() and showing and directly dismissing it it shows forever.

```
ProgressDialog waitDialog;
waitDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
waitDialog.show(this, "wait","wait");
waitDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: Are you implementing in Activity or Fragment Activity??

Comment: I call a function in oncreate() of my activity

Answer (score 1):

**DO this way.**

```
ProgressDialog waitDialog;
waitDialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "wait","wait");
5secondstask();
waitDialog.dismiss();
```

**UPDATE EXPLAINATION**

In your case not working because the progressdialog you create using `waitDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);` is reference by "waitDialog" variable. But when you call show method it returns another object of progressdialog. which is not reference by "waitDialog" variable.
Because show() is static method which returns new object of progressdialog.

Your case will also work if assign reference to "waitDialog" variable.

```
ProgressDialog waitDialog;
waitDialog=new ProgressDialog(this);
waitDialog=waitDialog.show(this, "wait","wait");//UPDATE here to work with your case
5secondstask();
waitDialog.dismiss();
```

Comment: Both versions I copied directly into my code seems not to work. In both versions the dialog doesn't show up. Thanks anyway.